# Adding Batch Dimension to tensorflow graph which was trained without batching support

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-processing, tensor, batching

I trained the network without batching, hence the input dimension of graph is (H,W,C) (not even [1,H,W,C]).
But during inference, I need predictions for multiple images (batched inference).
How can we achieve this

Comment: I don't think you can train without batching. Please show your code (the line with input dimension of (H,W,C))

Comment: Just figured out they are expanding the dimensions using expandims as the first op of the graph